# Count and distinct count in one LINQ expression

Tags: c#, .net, linq, c#-4.0

Is there anyway to combine the 2 linq expressions into one? I.e. so one LINQ expression will return both the DistCount and the NormCount into the 2 separate int variables.

```
DistCount = (from string row in myList[i]
                where row.Length > 0
                select row).Distinct().Count();

NormCount = (from string row in myList[i]
                where row.Length > 0
                select row).Count();
```

Comment: `var final = new {DistCount=1,NormCount=2};`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

do a `group` by row.  You'll then have the distinct count (# of groups) and the total (sum of `Count`s)

```
var q = (from string row in myList[i]
    where row.Length > 0
    group row by row into rowCount
    select new {rowCount.Key, rowCount.Count})

int distinct = q.Count();
int total = q.Sum(r=>r.Count);
```

Comment: Kind of hides the intent of the code, will need to be put into a separate method with a good name or commented. Performance is also questionable.

Comment: Remember a "ToList" at then end of q, or you will do the whole group by twice

Answer (score 4):

**To answer your question.** There's no built-in linq expression for that.

**Side note.** If you really need it you can create one.

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static Tuple<int, int> DistinctAndCount<T>(this IEnumerable<T> elements)
    {
        HashSet<T> hashSet = new HashSet<T>();
        int count = 0;
        foreach (var element in elements)
        {
            count++;
            hashSet.Add(element);
        }

        return new Tuple<int, int>(hashSet.Count, count);
    }
}
```

You can create your named return type instead of Tuple to make the usage easier.

Example usage will look like:

```
   var distinctAndCount = (from string row in myList[i]
                              where row.Length > 0 
                              select row
                             ).DistinctAndCount();
```

Or as I personally would prefer to write it:

```
   var distinctAndCount = myList[i].Where(row => row.Length > 0).DistinctAndCount();
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try selecting an anonymous type:

```
from string row in myList[i] 
where row.Length > 0
select new { 
    DistCount = row.Distinct().Count(), 
    NormCount = row.Count() 
}
```

Comment: row.Distinct().Count() will count the number of the distinct chars in the string row, not what the author needs